# Mailmerge result not displaying after connecting it with a database

Tags: database, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a mailmerge that I am currently developing. I connected the mailmerge to a database (a particular query in the database) as datasource  but I see nothing if I press Alt+f9. I understand that ctrl A and pressing F9 is for refreshing the data but it is still not working. Strangely it was showing before

Below is the mailmerge jargons when I toggle back:

`DATABASE  \d "X:\\PM\\PM-O\\PM-OQ\\PM-OQRA\\PROCESSES\\02_Cosmetics\\98_ Database\\99_Release\\Dossier_Developer.accdb" \c "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=X:\\PM\\PM-O\\PM-OQ\\PM-OQRA\\PROCESSES\\02_Cosmetics\\98_ Database\\99_Release\\Dossier_Developer.accdb;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=\"\";Jet OLEDB:System database=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False" \s "SELECT * FROM` Q_DOSSIER_LeapingBunny_S_C01_ConnectArticleNo`" \l "16" \b "191" \h`

Comment: What you have posted has no obvious connection to a mailmerge: it's the field code from a DATABASE field. As it is, the field code could apparently be shortened to: {DATABASE  \d "X:\\PM\\PM-O\\PM-OQ\\PM-OQRA\\PROCESSES\\02_Cosmetics\\98_ Database\\99_Release\\Dossier_Developer.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM Q_DOSSIER_LeapingBunny_S_C01_ConnectArticleNo" \l "16" \b "191" \h}

Comment: I am a bit confused. anytime I select database as my data source, it opens a directory which has only `+Connect to New Data Source` and `+NewSQLServerConnection`  and i always ignore these and navigate my way to where my datasource is, then I select my query of choice. The process is straightforward but I don`t know why it is not working

Comment: So what is the problem? Of itself, your DATABASE field has nothing to do with a mailmerge. The Word behaviour you describe is perfectly normal.

Comment: The database field was executed in a word document as Mailmerge but it is working now, I cannot explain why it is working again.